# set cookie with cgi-python scripts

Tags: python, cgi, setcookie

I'm trying to response from the server with a set-cookie header

my cgi script begins as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
from collections import defaultdict
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting
from MySQL import sql

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
mode = form.getvalue('mode')

print """Content-type: text/html\r\n"""
print """Set-Cookie: name=12345\r\n\r\n"""
```

However, when checking the response from the server on my Chrome..the debugger doesn't show any set-cookie header in the response part, and the set-cookie header is printed in the response part as part of the text, unlike the content-type header...

Any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are appending two newlines instead of one to the end of your "Content-Type" header, which is the standard separator between HTTP headers and body.

You should instead be emitting `\r\n` at the end of each header value (as opposed to `\n\n`)

When you are done emitting headers, you should print one extra `\r\n` to begin your message body.

EDIT: Additionally, you should either be using `sys.stdout.write(...)` or appending a trailing comma to your print statement to avoid its inserting the implicit newline.  E.g.,

`print "Header: Value\r\n",`

Comment: Hey..please check my edition..let me know if that's what you meant

Comment: It still doesn't work..I get the same result printed at the client :-(

Comment: Oh!,  Also, append a "," to the end of your print statement.  print will automatically append "\n" to each line.  So something like:

`print """Header: value\r\n""",`

Comment: But wouldn't it again make it two new lines?

Comment: And do I need to add it to both headers?

Comment: print will automatically append \n to each line if you do *not* include the trailing comma.

Comment: Yes, do that for both headers or use sys.stdout.write() instead of print (you will need to import sys)

Answer (score 0):

You should print the Set-Cookie line before the Content-type:text/html line.